# Why doesn't this change gui code work for Roblox Studio?

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to create a TextLabel that changes every 5 seconds. I have this code, but it doesn't work.

```
local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(part.Parent) —this is our gateway to getting the PlayerGui object.
  local PlayerUI = player:WaitForChild(“PlayerGui”)
  local txtLabel = PlayerUI[“Welcome_Text”].TextLabel
while x < 1 do
  wait(5)
  txtLabel.Text = “Welcome to The Shadow Realm!”
  wait(5)
  txtLabel.Text = “Warning: This game contains scenes that may be too scary for some roblox players”
end
```

I am getting an error message that says.

> ServerScriptService.Script:2: attempt to index global 'part' (a nil value)

I don't know where to put my gui.

Comment: You have not declared the variable `'part'` anywhere in your code, that is, it is `nil`–hence the error that says `attempt to index global 'part' (a nil value)`. You will also run into the same issue with the variable `'x'` because it is undeclared. Also, where will your above code be placed, and will it be in a `Script` or `LocalScript`?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally cut out the ```x=0``` bit. The code will be placed in a script, not a local script.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correctly understanding what you are trying to do, you should be able to create a `ScreenGui` and place it in `StartGui` so that every player will have it copied to his `PlayerGui` when he joins the game. You could place a `LocalScript` inside of that GUI that would control the text on screen.

I see your `LocalScript` looking something like this:

```
-- Customize names on your own; these are just generic placeholders.
-- The structure of the GUI would look like this:
--
-- ScreenGui
--    LocalScript
--    Frame
--        TextLabel

local WELCOME = "Welcome to the Shadow Realm!"
local WARNING = "Warning! This game contains scenes that may be too scary for some players"

local runService = game:GetService("RunService")

local gui = script.Parent
local frame = gui.Frame
local label = frame.TextLabel

local function update_text()
    label.Text = WELCOME
    wait(5)
    label.Text = WARNING
    return
end
runService.RenderStepped:Connect(update_text)
```

Making this a `LocalScript` within a client-side GUI shifts the overhead to the client and eliminates the need to use the method `Players::GetPlayerFromCharacter`.